# Would getting an Access Point potentially help fix my NAT?

Tags: nat, access-point, wireless-bridge

Not too long ago we switched internet providers to T-Mobile Home Internet and the speed has been a huge improvement, but recently a problem has risen to my attention of the NAT type on my family's Nintendo Switches being fairly restrictive for playing with other people.

Unfortunately while I have been assured by their service that it is getting worked on being added, currently they lack required options for port forwarding or opening the correct ports to help with it. I know the Access Point would have its own internal options which would probably include the options I would require, but I don't know if it would still run into the Gateway's system and the options would amount to nothing.

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow. I flagged this question for migration to superuser.com

Comment: Apologies, would be good to add that to the blurb on Stackexchange.com so that it's easy to identify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the options would amount to nothing so long as the T-Mobile device is acting as your router. The port forwards you wanted to set would still be unable to traverse the T-Mobile device to reach your access point or home router. You might check with T-Mobile if they have the option of setting their device into Bridged mode; that would basically bring raw internet onto the network ports on their device, and a home router with the port forwarding options you need could then be attached. Bear in mind that if they do that, you would be completely responsible for the access point / home router setup.

Comment: Correct answer, but this question should really not be here.

Comment: @Massimo I went with the exchange that seemed most appropriate.

Comment: yeh, as alsmost noone knows about superuser ;)

Comment: @djdomi You mean the stack that has the blurb "Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users" somehow strikes you as more appropriate than "Q&A for system and network administrators"? Because this is a network question, and I think I'd prefer asking that to people who profess themselves experts than general computer savvy people.

Comment: lol, no matter what ever, superuser.com mostly fit the same ;)